# copying a worksheet but it does not copy hidden rows / columns

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I have the following code in 2 different worksheets within the same workbook .
The first goes thru a loop for 21 days and the second does an entire month. ( loop size changes for days of month.)

```
Public Sub CopyDailyWorkbook()
'  dimensions variables as type
Dim SourceFileName As String    ' sets the file path of the Folder

Dim DestFileName As String
Dim Range   As Range
Dim SourceFile As Workbook   ' Sets the Source File Folder
Dim DestFile As Workbook     ' Sets the destination Folder file

' Initialsizes the variable directory
SourceFileName = FiletoCopy  ' Full Path for actual file to be copied
Set SourceFile = Workbooks.Open(SourceFileName)    ' opens the Excel file
Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = False    ' Unhides column's
Rows("1:500").EntireRow.Hidden = False    ' Unhides Rows

'Debug.Print " Sets file to be copied    " & SourceFileName
' copies  the Daily Report Worksheet
SourceFile.Sheets("Daily Report").Range("A3:Z500").Copy    '  Copies cells from source worksheet

SourceFile.Close SaveChanges:=False    ' Close the Excel file

' Pastes copied file into worksheet
Dim PasteDay As String
PasteDay = "Day " & DaysLoop
PasteDay = WorksheetFunction.Text(DaysLoop, "00")

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Day " & DaysLoop).Range("A1:Z500")    ' Worksheet to paste onto
Debug.Print " Sets file to be pasted to    " & ("Day " & DaysLoop) & " date = " & FileDayName

End Sub
```

I run the weekly to get infromation for the last 3 weeks and a monthly to get the info for the entire month.   The weekly can cross months  ( like Feb 17 to Mar 7 ) but the monthly is only from the first to last day of the month.

My problem is on the 3 week the days copy perfectly.  I get all the visiable cells and all the hidden ones. ( hidden cells are A120 to A220 and columns T thru Y )
But with the exact same code on the monthly I only get the visiable cells.  the hidden cells on the destination worksheet are blank. but it does copy all the visiable information for all the days in the month. 
I copied and pasted the code from the weekly. 
These are the only copy subroutines in the workbook

I am copying from the same woksheets from the source worksheets  and putting them on the the same worksheets on the destination folder.

Comment: Are you running the macro on one sheet, then selecting another, and running it? Your code would probably be improved (*maybe* fix the whole issue) by adding a reference to the worksheet for all the range variables.  At the start, you don't specify a workbook/worksheet you want the row and columns unhidden on.Also, where do you set `DaysLoop`?)

Comment: The days loop is set in an earlier subroutine.  I go it fixed though.. -- a vb programmer ( actually a salesman that used to do programming  ) came by the shop and helped me out.  the issue was that i was running the subs in different worksheets but had the variables in the main module.    I cleaned it up and put all the subs in the same module and that fixed it.     Thanks for looking into it